# How to Retrieve Just the Time from DateTime Object but retaining the datatype

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have some timestamp data. I changed its type from string to `datetime`. It looks like this:

```
1    2020-11-06 09:42:13.830995
2    2020-11-06 09:42:14.195429
3    2020-11-06 09:42:14.378181
4    2020-11-06 09:42:36.801859
                ...            
59   2020-11-06 10:30:06.299660
60   2020-11-06 10:31:13.824763
61   2020-11-06 10:31:21.924866
62   2020-11-06 10:31:23.016526
63   2020-11-06 10:34:21.289348
Name: timestamp, Length: 64, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Is there any way to retrieve just  the TIME part from `datetime` data with the result being of the same datatype.? I did it this way:
 `df.timestamp.dt.time`
to get the desired results:

```
1     09:42:13.830995
2     09:42:14.195429
3     09:42:14.378181
4     09:42:36.801859
           ...       
59    10:30:06.299660
60    10:31:13.824763
61    10:31:21.924866
62    10:31:23.016526
63    10:34:21.289348
Name: Log_Timestamp, Length: 64, dtype: object
```

BUT as you can see the datatype is no longer `datetime`.

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: It is expected, python object `time` is not datetimes.

Comment: In pandas, you cannot have date and time separately. Just use datetime and ignore the date part.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected, python object `time` is is not `datetime`.

Close, what you need are timedeltas:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.timestamp.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```